# Best way to execute code on remote machine

Tags: unix, ssh, server, cuda, nohup

I am looking for the best way to execute code on a distant machine. Ideally, I am looking for a solution such as Cuda which provides the opportunity to allocate executions on GPU or CPU, but for distinct machine.

I tried distinct ways to do that :

- I connect my machines with ssh, export my script, execut it. No particular issue, but not very handy. But maybe this solution could be optimise. Because I open my ssh connection with the terminal, or termius.
- I try another way with mosh, same outcomes, but quicker.
- Currently, I am working on a Spyder kernel to have a direct link in the place of execution.
- I've seen there is also a possibility with a nohup connection, but I have to work on this solution to understand well the possibilities.

Everything works well, but I am looking for a more convenient solution.

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: There is [rCUDA](http://www.rcuda.net/). But if you find ssh inconvenient, it is unlikely you will be happier with rCUDA.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I do not use the ssh connection in the right way, because mostly people who want to work remotely use ssh connection. The main issue is that I have to keep the connection on.

Comment: You can launch your work in the background.  Then it will not die if the ssh connection is interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use sshfs along to ssh to mount the remote filesystem on your machine it's easier than always copy the code by hand, if so I would recommend to use screen or something like that that if the connection breaks it offers no problems.

Personal I like to work with Visual Studio Code and the ssh fs extension for this purpose.

An other alternative is to work with X2Go. X2Go enables you to access a graphical desktop of a computer over a low bandwidth (or high bandwidth) connection.